# What to do with a point of usage that's merely interesting?

Tags: discussion

Recently I wrote a sentence that had this form: I think this group includes any number of round items (apples, oranges, beach balls, etc.).

I had no doubt that the final period was correct, but I thought the odd look of the period-parenthesis-period structure would be a mildly interesting point of discussion, which is not the sort of thing considered appropriate for this site. Moreover, I couldn't find any questions and answers on the site that addressed the question of correctness of this punctuation. (Many came close, but did not precisely address it.)

So, my dilemma is that it's a question that is sort of worth asking, but seems a bit too much in the realm of questions that engender mostly discussion and debate, and hence doesn't quite fit, yet there's no other place it would fit better. Furthermore, the discussion that already exists here that comes close is already extensive, yet STILL doesn't answer this exact point.

Is it too trivial a question to ask? Is it off-topic? What about any question that seems to have been discussed *ad nauseam*, yet still isn't precisely answered? What to do, meta users?

Comment: Is this more towards a discussion or do you think there is a definitive answer?

Comment: Well, I get the impression that discussion is somewhat discouraged on the main site, but allowed here. So, yes, I'm interested in discussing this dilemma. I don't think there is a definitive answer, but I would like some opinions.

Answer (score 3):

ELU "dealt with" this point of usage here...

> [How to deal with abbreviations like 'etc.' at the end of parenthesis which are closing a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23022/how-to-deal-with-abbreviations-like-etc-at-the-end-of-parenthesis-which-are-c)

If you want further discussion, post a comment there. Or "bump" it with an edit/answer, or add a bonus to stimulate community interest.

Comment: Actually, I just edited it myself for a typo. Perhaps it'll be a hotbed of discussion soon!